# differential equation of motion - how to deal with squared differentials

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is probably something pretty elementary. But...

The equation given is $\frac{1}{2}m \dot x^2 - gmx = E$

and the assignment is to solve it to show you get the same thing as Newton's equation of motion. I just want to know if I am approaching solving this correctly.

When I move the variables around to solve the differential, I end up with $$\dot x^2 = \frac{2(E+gmx)}{m} \Rightarrow \dot x = \sqrt{\frac{2(E+gmx)}{m}}$$ and then I am left with what seems like a pretty ugly integral. Maybe that's just the way it is. But when I tru to integrate this I end up with $$\frac{2}{3}\left(\frac{(2(E+gmx)}{m}\right)^{3/2}t$$ or something like it and I know that is wrong-- basically I am at  loss of how to approach something like this. Maybe its jut integration by parts or some such? Should I be changing the E to something in terms of x and t? or is there a simpler approach to this kind of differential generally?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Try writing the integration part as:

$$\displaystyle \int \dfrac{\sqrt{m}}{\sqrt{E + g m x}} dx = \int \sqrt{2} dt$$

Let $u = E + g m x \rightarrow du = g m dx$

Can you finish it?

**Spoiler**

> $x(t) = \dfrac{gt^2}{2} - \dfrac{E}{gm} \pm gc t +\dfrac{g c^2}{2}$

Comment: OK, from there it would seem I end up with $\int{\frac{1}{\sqrt{u}}\frac{1}{gm}du} = \int \sqrt{2}dt$, correct? and then i can just integrate the $\frac{\sqrt{m}}{gm}\int{\frac{1}{\sqrt{u}}du}$ and get $u^{1/2}+c$?

Comment: thanks that helps a lot. maybe i am just too tired to think these days. :-(

Comment: Oops, I think you meant $2/(g \sqrt{m}) \sqrt{u} + c$

Comment: yeah. see what fatigue does. $2\sqrt{u}+c = \sqrt{2}t$

Comment: Yeah - it is hard to solve problems when very tired - I make all kind of errors! Also, see my previous comment - don't forget the constant! Regards

Comment: The Ace of the Spoiler! +1

Comment: @amWhy: I wonder if they can refrain from looking at the spoiler? :-) Happy Monday, time to get to work!

Comment: Happy Monday, back-at-ya'!

Comment: One other question just occurred to me -- are the constants of integration the same ? They aren't, are they?

Comment: Well, we are finding the indefinite integral since we have no constants. The solution includes a constant, so if we are given some initial condition, we can solve for it. We basically found the general solution for all $t$.

Comment: so there is no +c on the $\sqrt{2}t$ term, right?

Comment: You would combine the $c$ from the LHS and the RHS integral on one side of the equation. So, yes, there is a $c$ on the RHS. Sorry if I misunderstood.

Comment: ah, so you just count both constants as one. but when I do the multiplication out I get $x(t) = gt^2 +\sqrt{2}cgt+\frac{c^2g}{2}-\frac{E}{mg}$

Comment: That is close to mine, but I am at work and do not have time to figure out. Looks like you lost a $(1/2)$ on the $gt^2$ term and can combine the $\sqrt{2}$ with the $c$ in the $cgt$ term.